# "Ambiguous column name" exception when using order-by in collection mapping

Tags: nhibernate

Consider this class that represents a node in a hierarchical structure:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual int Position
    {
        get { return Parent == null ? -1 : Parent.Children.IndexOf(this); }
        set { }
    }
}
```

The mapping looks like this (as NHibernate does not support lists in bidirectional associations, I use a bag here and have the children determine their position automatically):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="AmbiguousColumn" assembly="AmbiguousColumn" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Node">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <bag name="Children" inverse="true" cascade="all" order-by="Position">
      <key column="Parent" />
      <one-to-many class="Node" />
    </bag>
    <many-to-one name="Parent" />
    <property name="Position" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

To get all nodes with their children loaded I'd use a query like this:

```
var nodes = session.QueryOver<Node>()
                   .Fetch(x => x.Children).Eager
                   .List();
```

However, executing this results in an exception:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
>    [...(sql)...] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Ambiguous column name 'Position'.

The SQL:

```
SELECT
    this_.Id as Id0_1_,
    this_.Parent as Parent0_1_,
    this_.Position as Position0_1_,
    children2_.Parent as Parent3_,
    children2_.Id as Id3_,
    children2_.Id as Id0_0_,
    children2_.Parent as Parent0_0_,
    children2_.Position as Position0_0_
FROM
    Node this_
left outer join
    Node children2_
        on this_.Id=children2_.Parent
ORDER BY
    Position
```

I understand why this happens: NH joins the same table twice, but uses the order clause without qualifying the column name.

The question is: how can I make this scenario work? Resorting to  instead of  is probably difficult as I'd like to have a bidirectional relation.

There are a couple of similar question on SO, but nowhere did I find an actual solution.

---

**Update**: the error is database/driver specific. Using the Sql Server CE (e.g. SqlServerCeDriver and MsSqlCe40Dialect) I get the proper query. Using Sql Server (e.g. Sql2008ClientDriver and MsSql2012Dialect) produces the unqualified queries.

According to my own tests, this behavior still exists in the master branch on github.

A gist with a test case: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5377535

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the cause of the problem and viable workarounds:

The cause of the issue is the fact that the column is called "Position", which is a reserved word in ODBC according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

This combined with the fact that the default value for NH's `hbm2ddl.keywords` property is set to "keywords" somehow caused NH not to qualify the order-by clause, probably because it though "Position" was a keyword, not a column.

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/06/24/auto-quote-table-column-names.aspx

Ways to fix it:

1) Use a different name for the property - one that isn't a keyword. In this case, `PositionInParent` would have worked without any issues.

2) Quote the order by clause properly using back-ticks.

```
<bag name="Children" inverse="true" cascade="all" order-by="`Position`">
```

Or whatever it takes in your mapping API of choice, e.g. in mapping by code:

```
cls.Bag(x => x.Children,
        map =>
        {
            map.Inverse(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            map.Key(key => key.Column("Parent"));
            map.OrderBy("`Position`"); // note that you must not use a lambda expression in this case
        },
        map => map.OneToMany());
```

3) Disable keyword auto import, ie. set `hbm2ddl.keywords` to `none` (neither `keywords` nor `auto-quote` will work):

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
```

Or programmatically:

```
config.DataBaseIntegration(db => db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.None);
```

You can still auto-quote reserved words by calling `SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns` just before building the session factory.

```
SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(config);
```

I'll stick with approach 3 for now as it is the most painless so far.

Comment: Damn. The NHibernate test project has `<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>` by default. This why I thought it was a bug. I've deleted my answer as it was wrong.

Comment: @penfold Don't worry, your answer led my efforts to the right direction. Without your "wrong" answer, I probably wouldn't have played with the NH source. I wrote a unit test inside the NH source which to my surprise didn't fail. I checked any differences between their test setup and my test app and found hbm2ddl.keywords to be different.